# Can I use JSON light format using WCF Data Services Client without referencing service metadata?

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

I have a client application that is consuming a WCF Data Services OData service (both are v5.3.0). I'd like the client application to communicate with the service using JSON, instead of Atom Pub XML, which is the default.

Is this possible without without providing an IEdmModel instance? It's possible to do when using the Atom format:

```
        var ctx = new DataServiceContext(_oDataSvcUri, DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3)
        {
            IgnoreMissingProperties = true
        };

        // this isn't explicitly needed, as it uses Atom by default
        ctx.Format.UseAtom();

        return ctx;
```

Whereas for this to work using JSON, this is an example of what's required:

```
        var ctx = new DataServiceContext(_oDataSvcUri, DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3)
            {
                IgnoreMissingProperties = true
            };

        const string svcMetadata = "*insert contents of http://example.com/YourData.svc/$metadata here*";

        var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(svcMetadata));

        IEdmModel edmModel = EdmxReader.Parse(xmlReader);

        ctx.Format.UseJson(edmModel);

        ctx.ResolveName = type => type.FullName;
        ctx.ResolveType = typeName => Type.GetType(typeName + ", " + "MyDomainModelAssemblyName");

        return ctx;
```

I'd like to be able to use the JSON format without specifying an IEdmModel like you can with Atom. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to read a JSON Light payload using the WCF Data Services client without having a server model client-side. JSON Light payloads are clean and small precisely because they assume that the client has an understanding of the server model and can compute all the extra metadata that's left out by using that.

However, you don't necessarily have to use EdmxReader to parse the server's $metadata document yourself. If you generated the client-side classes using "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio and you use the derived DataServiceContext class (not DataServiceContext directly), the generated derived class has some configuration already set up to let you call `ctx.Format.UseJson()` without needing to explicitly provide a model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jen. The assembly that contains the model on the server side is available to me on the client side (I own both), and what I'm after is a way to consume the service using JSON without having to update any service references/update metadata xml files or strings in my client apps. It seems like this should be possible since I pass in the type to deserialise to when calling the CreateQuery method on the DataServiceContext:

`dataServiceContext.CreateQuery<MyEntityType>("MyEntitySetName");`

Comment: Unfortunately the type alone isn't sufficient. The client needs the full model to be able to read JSON Light.  If you can't update the service reference or change the string resources on the client, you could use the constructible API in EdmLib (availabe through the Microsoft.Data.Edm.Library namespace in the Microsoft.Data.Edm dll) to create an instance of IEdmModel.  For example: EdmModel model = new EdmModel();  model.AddElement(new EntityType(...)). The API usage should be fairly discoverable, but ask if you have questions there (if you decide to go this route).

Comment: That should be "new EdmEntityType()", not "new EntityType()", but I'm over the 5 minute time limit for editing comments :)